# Using Box Icons in Vuejs for loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using the box icons web component and i'm trying to figure out how use the icon in my link array for each item. I'm just not sure hot to go about doing that.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="linkbox">
    <a :href="link.href" class="link" v-for="link in links" :key="link.href" @click="goTo($event, link.href)">
      {{ link.name }}
      <box-icon></box-icon>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      links:[
        { name: 'Twitter', href: 'http://www.twitter.com', icon: 'twitter' },
        { name: 'Github', href: 'http://www.github.com' },
        { name: 'Linkedin', href: 'http://www.linkedin.com' },
        { name: 'Patreon', href: 'http://www.linkedin.com' },
        { name: 'Linkedin', href: 'http://www.linkedin.com' },
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Bind the icon name to the `icon` field from the link :

```html
<box-icon :name="link.icon"></box-icon>
```